# Explain why $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are orthogonal complements.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I would like to learn how to prove that $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are orthogonal complements.

I understand the intuition behind why this is the case, and my proof would be the following:

> The only vector common to a subspace and its orthogonal complement is
> $0$, so if the subspace spans all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the orthogonal
> complement can contain only the $0$ vector.

But I am not sure if this is sufficient.

Comment: What is your definition of orthogonal complement? Your proof ought to follow that definition closely.

Comment: "If W is a subspace of $R^n$, then the set of all vectors in $R^n$ that are orthogonal to every vector in W is called the orthogonal complement of W."

Comment: $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$ for any vector space $V$, so you need only show one direction. To see $\{0\}^\perp = \mathbb{R}^n$, observe that $\left< 0, x\right> = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @infinitylord Could you tell me what this notation means: ⟨0,⟩ ? I've not seen this before

Comment: @vardo It is the standard notation for an inner product. You may know it in the special case of a "dot product" given by $\left<u, x\right> = u \cdot x$.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thank you!

Comment: @infinitylord why does the fact that $(^⊥)^⊥=$ mean that I only need to show one direction?

Comment: @vardo If you know $\{0\}^\perp = \mathbb{R}^n$, then you automatically get $(\mathbb{R}^n)^\perp = (\{0\}^\perp)^\perp = \{0\}$